# Connect AWS SQS to Apache-Flink

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, amazon-sqs

Why is AWS SQS not a default connector for [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/)? Is there some technical limitation to doing this? Or was it just something that didn't get done? I want to implement this, any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Did you ever end up writing one?

Comment: Any word on this? I'd be interested in this too.

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late for an answer to the original question... I wrote a SQS consumer as a SourceFunction, using the Java Messaging Service library for SQS:

```
SQSConsumer extends RichParallelSourceFunction<String> {
   private volatile boolean isRunning;
   private transient AmazonSQS sqs;
   private transient SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
   private transient ExecutorService consumerExecutor;

   @Override
   public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
      String region = ...
      AWSCredentialsProvider credsProvider = ...
      // may be use a blocking array backed thread pool to handle surges?
      consumerExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
      ClientConfiguration clientConfig = PredefinedClientConfigurations.defaultConfig();
      this.sqs = AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).withCredentials(credsProvider)
            .withClientConfiguration(clientConfig)
            .withExecutorFactory(()->consumerExecutor).build();
      this.connectionFactory = new SQSConnectionFactory(new ProviderConfiguration(), sqs);
      this.isRunning = true;
   }

   @Override
   public void run(SourceContext<String> ctx) throws Exception {
      SQSConnection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
      // ack each msg explicitly
      Session session = connection.createSession(false, SQSSession.UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      Queue queue = session.createQueue(<queueName>);
      MessageConsumer msgConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
      msgConsumer.setMessageListener(msg -> {
          try {
              String msgId = msg.getJMSMessageID();
              String evt = ((TextMessage) msg).getText();
              ctx.collect(evt);
              msg.acknowledge();
          } catch (JSMException e) {
              // log and move on the next msg or bail with an exception
              // have a dead letter queue is configured so this message is not lost
              // msg is not acknowledged so it may be picked up again by another consumer instance
          }
      };
      // check if we were canceled
      if (!isRunning) {
          return;
      }
      connection.start();
      while (!consumerExecutor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
          // keep waiting
      }
  }
            

  @Override
  public void cancel() {
      isRunning = false;
      // this method might be called before the task actually starts running
      if (sqs != null) {
          sqs.shutdown();
      }
      if(consumerExecutor != null) {
           consumerExecutor.shutdown();
           try {
               consumerExecutor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES); 
           } catch (Exception e) {
               //log e
           }
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void close() throws Exception {
       cancel();
       super.close();
   }
}
```

Note if you are using a standard SQS queue you may have to de-dup the messages depending on whether exactly-once guarantees are required.

Reference:
[Working with JMS and Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-java-message-service-jms-client.html)

Comment: Thank you for the example, quite useful. May I ask what `credsProvider` you use? I am getting `java.io.NotSerializableException: com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider` for `ProfileCredentialsProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there is no connector for AWS SQS in Apache Flink. Have a look at the already [existing connectors](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-connectors). I assume you already know about this, and would like to give some pointers. I was also looking for an SQS connector recently and found this [mail thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-dev/201707.mbox/%3C5578C077-D77A-4DB8-B07F-83293F8C8786@arcticwolf.com%3E).

[Apache Kinesis Connector](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kinesis) is somewhat similar to what you can implement on this. See whether you can get a start on this using this connector.