# How to consume Amazon S3 objects from Flink?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, architecture, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

#### Problem

We have an Apache Flink application which was designed to read events from Kafka and emit the calculated results into ElasticSearch. Because of some resourcing problems we have to fallback from Kafka to Amazon S3.

The messages are published to Amazon S3 buckets in small batches in [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/) format.

The files are organized in the following way: `/{year}/{month}/{day}/{hour}`.
So, in every hour we create a new folder under which we store the most recent events.

#### Design

As we have seen Amazon S3 can emit [notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) whenever a new object has been created.
We can push these notifications either into an SQS or into a Lambda.

- As it was stated in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231656/connect-aws-sqs-to-apache-flink/) SQS is not supported by Flink.
- In case of Lambda we can get the S3 object and push it on the Kinesis Data Stream

We have also found alternative solutions to avoid writing custom Lambda function:

- [Via AWS Data Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/streaming-data-from-amazon-s3-to-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-using-aws-dms/)
- [Via Athena](https://amplify-analytics.workshop.aws/05-adding-custom-analytics/02-kinesis-firehose-s3-athena.html)

#### Question

But in all cases we ended up using KDS. Is there any alternative to push data from Amazon S3 to Flink on object creation?

Comment: Flink sources are just interfaces one has to implement. You could develop your own source that knows how to fetch data from Amazon SQS.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Could you please point me to a sample implementation?

Comment: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/sourcessinks/

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Is there any option which does not require to implement our own source function?

Comment: I don't believe there's an active source out there today, so no unfortunately.

Comment: Do you even need SQS notification? Wouldn't it suffice to let Flink scan S3 bucket every hour?

Comment: @ArvidHeise The thing is that we need to process it as soon as it is available.

Comment: @ArvidHeise If you have a bucket which has many key prefixes, listing the bucket every hour may take a significant amount of time.

Comment: @PeterCsala have you had to do time aggregations in this use case?

Comment: @bottaio Yes, we have used 30 seconds windows.

Comment: @PeterCsala of event time? what watermark strategy did you use if so?

Comment: @bottaio Yes, we have used event time. We have used `TumblingEventTimeWindows` for WindowAssigner and `WatermarkStrategy.<Event>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(...).withTimestampAssigner(...)` for WatermarkStrategy.

Comment: @PeterCsala I am afraid of this strategy a bit. Not sure about your use case but we might get hundreds of files at once every hour and they all contain 1h worth of data. That probably means we have to set out of orderness to 1h and also be careful about the order of file listings (for correctness on job restarts). This also means that we have 1h worth of latency introduced to the pipeline (plus the time window length). I wonder if we can somehow mitigate this effect :)

Comment: @bottaio Our ndjson files contains events only for 1 minute, so it is not that huge problem for us.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the [readFile](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/environment/StreamExecutionEnvironment.html#readFile-org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat-java.lang.String-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.FileProcessingMode-long-) method to scan an s3 bucket for new objects. When configured with `FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY` and an appropriate polling interval this can work quite well. The key is to define a `TextInputFormat` with a customized `FilePathFilter`. The file path filter will recurse through the "directories" in your s3 bucket, and since you've structured them with date parts, the recursing can find new files without scanning through lots of objects in the bucket.

Here is what the custom `FilePathFilter` will look like. I've been using similar code to discover hundreds of new files every few minutes with this, and it's worked without any issues.

```java
public class S3FilePathFilter extends FilePathFilter {

    Pattern datePartsFromPath = Pattern.compile("\\/(?<year>\\d{4})\\/?(?<month>\\d{2})?\\/?(?<day>\\d{2})?\\/?(?<hour>\\d{2})?");

    private final Duration ageLimit;

    public S3FilePathFilter(Duration ageLimit) {
        this.ageLimit=ageLimit;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean filterPath(Path filePath) {

        Matcher matcher = datePartsFromPath.matcher(filePath.toString());

        if (matcher.find()) {
            ZonedDateTime limit = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")).minus(ageLimit);

            int year = NumberUtils.toInt(matcher.group("year"));
            int month = NumberUtils.toInt(matcher.group("month"), limit.getMonthValue());
            int day = NumberUtils.toInt(matcher.group("day"), limit.getDayOfMonth());
            int hour = NumberUtils.toInt(matcher.group("hour"), limit.getHour());

            if (year != limit.getYear()) {
                return year < limit.getYear();
            }

            if (month != limit.getMonthValue()) {
                return month < limit.getMonthValue();
            }

            if (day != limit.getDayOfMonth()) {
                return day < limit.getDayOfMonth();
            }

            return hour < limit.getHour();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need `month1`, `month2` and `month3` groups?

Comment: I cleaned up the regex, now there is only one capture group per date part

Comment: Thanks, now it makes more sense to me :D