# At_Least_Once Checkpoint With S3 Source seems to block the event source for checkpointing duration

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

i am trying to build a system with real-time streaming processing with flink having s3 as source and elastic as sink.

i have tried out 4 cases for checkpoints in total.

1. Exactly_Once with Aligned Checkpoints.
2. Exactly_Once with unAligned Checkpoints.
3. At_Least_Once with max 1 concurrent Checkpoint.
4. At_Least_Once with max 2 concurrent Checkpoint.

Exactly_Once with unAligned Checkpoints seems to have the least delay in Publishing to Sink.

While Delay for the remaining three Seems to be similar.

As Per docs: At_Least_Once should not block the events for one stream during checkpointing in case of delay in alignment.

is this behaviour altered in case of file system based sources?

Details about the job:--

we have another service that is writing files to S3 in real time.
the part files are getting closed every 1 min duration.

flink job is consuming from this s3 path using env.readFile in PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY mode with window size of 30s.

we were expecting a max processing delay of 5m, but with
case 2:-- we are observing 8-10m of delay.
case 1,3,4 :--  delay of 10-14m.

we are running this job with 16 similar sources.

i am able to see that checkpoint delay is due to backpressure from two of the sources. whose tps is 180 and 90 respectively and their alignment delays are ~7m and ~6m.

however we are able to see that resource consumption remains pretty stable during the entire period. memory spike is to max 70% of heap.

Comment: The short answer is "no, there's nothing special about file sources that would affect this". But it's not clear exactly what you are observing, or why you suspect this isn't working as expected. It might help to know what the job is doing, whether you are using `env.readFile` or the `FileSource`, and how long the alignment delays are (and how much data has to be buffered).

Comment: hi @DavidAnderson, i have updated with details. please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: How many files are in the buckets/directories being monitored?

Comment: for each stream there is approximately 1y*12m*24h*60m = 17280 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ingesting from S3 in this fashion performs poorly and is expensive (because it's doing ListObjects for each iteration).

A better solution would be to use a custom SQS source (AFAIK there is no official one) using [Amazon S3 Event Notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html). Here is [a sample implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69741750/2000823).

Comment: thank you david, i will try it out.

Comment: hi @David, I was wondering if I apply a lifecycle policy on S3 to shift objects above 30 days into glaciers. will those objects still be part of iterating objects in flink?

note:-- objects in s3 are not modified once committed for us.

Comment: I would guess that those expired objects are no longer listed as being present in the bucket, but I have no experience with this.

Comment: okay, thank you david

Comment: S3 LIST operation does not care about the storage class. If a LIST prefix condition matches to filter the object that are in glacier still it will result in list operation response. And it needs a special API request to restore it from glacier. If you trigger GET request for a glacier object then you will get an exception something like `Unable to perform download operations on GLACIER objects. You must restore the object to be able to perform the operation`

Comment: thank you @JayaAnanthram for updating, we have bypassed this issue by creating a new bucket with replication enabled over the current bucket and also adding a lifecycle policy to delete old files from the current bucket.